# Jasmine: Testing that a method passed in as an argument to another method gets run

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, axios, jasmine, karma-jasmine

My code is as follows

```js
//agency_controller.js
import axios from 'axios';

export const getProducerNamesAndBillingPlan = ({ agencyId = '', onSuccess= (x) => x } = {} )  => {
  if(!!agencyId) {
    axios.get('/agency/' + agencyId)
         .then(response => onSuccess.call(this, response['data']))
         .catch(error => console.error(error))
  }
}
```

```js
//agency_controller.spec.js
import { getProducerNamesAndBillingPlan } from "../../../../app/javascript/packs/controllers/agencies_controller";
import axios from 'axios';

const mockAxiosPromise = (response) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, _reject) => {
    resolve({ status: 200, data: response});
  });
}

describe('#getProducerNamesAndBillingPlan', () => {
...
it('calls the given onSuccess method if the request is successful', () => {
    spyOn(axios, 'get').and.callFake(() => {
      return mockAxiosPromise('foo')
    })

    const mockMethod = (x) => console.log(x)

    spyOn(console.log, 'call')

    getProducerNamesAndBillingPlan({ agencyId: 1, onSuccess: mockMethod })

    expect(console.log.call).toHaveBeenCalledWith('foo')
  })
})
```

I can tell that the code is working because when I run the test, 'foo' gets logged to the console. However the test still fails:

```sh
#getProducerNamesAndBillingPlan calls the given onSucess method if the request is sucessful FAILED
        Expected spy call to have been called with [ 'foo' ] but it was never called.
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (spec/javascripts/packs/controllers/agencies_controller.spec.js:1:17348)
```

Same happens with `expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith('foo')`. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `axios.get()` method returns a promise, but the `getProducerNamesAndBillingPlan` function does not return it. You call it in the test case. When the code executes the expect statement, the promise is not resolved or rejected, so your `onSuccess` method was not called before the assertion.

Use `async/await` in test case to make sure the promise is resolved or rejected before the assertion.

`agency_controller.js`:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

export const getProducerNamesAndBillingPlan = ({ agencyId = '', onSuccess = (x) => x } = {}) => {
  if (!!agencyId) {
    return axios
      .get('/agency/' + agencyId)
      .then((response) => onSuccess.call(this, response['data']))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }
};
```

`agency_controller.spec.js`:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import { getProducerNamesAndBillingPlan } from './agency_controller';

describe('#getProducerNamesAndBillingPlan', () => {
  it('calls the given onSuccess method if the request is successful', async () => {
    spyOn(axios, 'get').and.resolveTo({ status: 200, data: 'foo' });
    const mockMethod = (x) => console.log(x);
    spyOn(console, 'log');
    await getProducerNamesAndBillingPlan({ agencyId: 1, onSuccess: mockMethod });
    expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith('foo');
  });
});
```

Test result:

```
Executing 1 defined specs...
Running in random order... (seed: 00239)

Test Suites & Specs:

1. #getProducerNamesAndBillingPlan
   ✔ calls the given onSuccess method if the request is successful (5ms)

>> Done!


Summary:

  Passed
Suites:  1 of 1
Specs:   1 of 1
Expects: 1 (0 failures)
Finished in 0.01 seconds
```